# Collect_set vs Approx_count_distinct Performance Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm applying window functions on a Dataframe, and I want to count distinct values. The goal is to count the number of orders for each seller in D-1 (D may change for each seller).

I see two options: `size(collect_set())` or `approx_count_distinct()`

```
my_window = (Window.partitionBy("seller_id").orderBy(col("dt_ref").cast(LongType())).rangeBetween(-60*60*24), 0))


df = (
  df
  .withColumn("total_orders", size(collect_set(("order_id")).over(my_window)))
  .withColumn("total_orders_2", approx_count_distinct("order_id", rsd=0.0).over(my_window)))
)
```

According to Spark docs, if you want exact results, you should use `count_distinct`, but it can't be used with window fuctions (only groupby). So the best way is to use `approx_count_distinct` with  rsd=0.0 or use `size(collect_set())`?

Both ways generates the same results. I wonder which is faster.